# std::copy_n and reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, copy, reinterpret-cast

```
uint    data1;
ushort  data2;
ushort  data3;
uchar   data4[8];

std::uint8_t buff[16];
std::uint8_t* out = buff;

out = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(&quid.data1), 4, out);
out = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(&quid.data2), 2, out);
out = std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(&quid.data3), 2, out);

std::copy_n(quid.data4, 8, out);
```

Why will the result in `out` will be different if I don't use `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: You really should show the `quid` struct. Otherwise this question really makes no sense. And even then it makes me shiver.

Comment: Why'd you delete your question about decimal digits? I was almost done with my answer.

Comment: I thought my question was a bad question,I will re-open it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result will be different because `&x` has type `T *`, where `T` is the type of `x`, and pointer arithmetic treats `+ 1` as "advancing the pointer by `sizeof(T)`", so that in effect you treat a pointer as a pointer into an array of elements of that type.

If you change the type of the pointer, you're going to treat the memory it's pointing to as an array of elements of a different type -- for example, treating an `int` as an array of `char`s.

Comment: yes but even if I use a int type without reinterpret_cast namely sizeof will return 4, and then I pass count argument = 1 (instead of 4), the result will still wrong

Comment: @Guillaume07: Sure, but there's a difference between writing one number into one char (and not writing in any of the other chars) and writing lots of individual chars into lots of chars. Remember that `copy_n` does a `+ 1` on both the input and the output iterator!

Answer (score 4):

```
std::copy_n(&quid.data1, 4, out);
```

works as if `quid.data1` were declared as `uint data1[4]`. The result is that `quid.data1` is copied to `out[0]` and the 3 other elements of `out` get a garbage.

```
std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<std::uint8_t*>(&quid.data1), 4, out);
```

treats the contents of `data1` as an array of 4 chars, that would work if `sizeof(uint)==4`.